# Slice Message And End Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Does anyone know how you can get the content of a message (message.content) and slice it. It's hard to explain so hear is an example.

```
Message - !This Is Just An Example / Hi
```

Do you know how to slice it so you will get First and The second part separately? Any way to do it so I can cut in between "/" so I will get -

'This Is Just An Example'

&

'Hi'

Comment: Please include the code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have edited it so you know what I mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the split method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp).

```py
message = '!This Is Just An Example / Hi'
message_parts = message.split('/')
```

In this example, `message_parts` would be a list with two items in it: '!This Is Just An Example ' and ' Hi'.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this response! Do you know know how to only get one of the parts? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure thing! If you want to get the first part, you can use `first_part = message_parts[0]`. If you want the second part, just swap the `0` for a `1`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()` splits a string into an Array based on given character(s), you can then access any individual index of said array.

```
const str = '!This Is Just An Example / Hi';

const arr = str.split('/');
// arr => ['!This Is Just An Example ', ' Hi']

console.log(arr[0]);
// '!This Is Just An Example '

console.log(arr[1]);
// ' Hi'
```